# Multiword Synonyms in Elasticsearch Full text document

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose we have following mapping in the elasticsearch :

```
  PUT /synonyms_test/
  {
     "settings": {
        "index": {
           "max_result_window": "5000000",
           "queries.cache.enabled": true,
           "requests.cache.enable": true
        },
        "analysis": {
           "filter": {
              "synonym_filter": {
                 "type": "synonym",
                 "synonyms": [
                    "USA, America, United States of America, The United States"
                 ],
                 "tokenizer": "keyword"
              }
           },
           "analyzer": {
              "synonyms_analyzer": {
                 "filter": [
                    "synonym_filter",
                    "lowercase"
                 ],
                 "tokenizer": "standard"
              }
           }
        }
     },
     "mappings": {
        "synonyms_index": {
           "properties": {
              "full_text": {
                 "type": "text",
                 "analyzer": "synonyms_analyzer",
                 "search_analyzer": "synonyms_analyzer"
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Below is the list of three indexed documents with synonyms.

```
  POST synonyms_test/synonyms_index/1
  {
     "full_text": "Washington is capital of USA"
  }

  POST synonyms_test/synonyms_index/2
  {
     "full_text": "Washington is capital of the America"
  }

  POST synonyms_test/synonyms_index/3
  {
     "full_text": "Washington is capital of the United States of America"
  }
```

Searching with multiword synonym does not work. I expect "United States of America" to be converted as synonyms in elasticsearch and elasticsearch should match all three docs.

```
  GET synonyms_test/synonyms_index/_search
  {
     "query": {
        "match": {
           "full_text": {
              "query": "Washington United States of America",
              "operator": "And"
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

If I change the type of tokenizer in synonym_filter to standard then even typing states bring all three results which I do not want.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the synonym replacement instead of merge. So change

```
"USA, America, United States of America, The United States" 
to
"America, United States of America, The United States=>USA"
```

See the guide for details here
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/multi-word-synonyms.html